# Google API Read Pull Queue Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pull-queue

I'm trying to read a pull queue in java (Google API)

Here is the code :

```
static HttpTransport newTransport() {
        HttpTransport result = new NetHttpTransport();
        GoogleUtils.useMethodOverride(result);
        GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
        headers.setApplicationName("Google-TaskQueueSample/1.0");
        result.defaultHeaders = headers;
        return result;
    }
```

And my imports:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
```

I have 2 errors in my code:
the methods

> useMethodOverride

and

> defaultHeaders

doesn't exists and i took this code from the documentation here : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-pull